# Firebase Cloud Function to trigger Firebase Messaging not sending Notification

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a `PushNotification` via **Cloud Messaging** when a document is added inside a collection of a user called `notifications`. I am saving the `token` for the user as suggested in the docs in a `arrayUnion` in a field called `messagingTokens`.

Additionally the notification should only be sent if a field called `isPushEnabled` is true. With this information I build this `cloud function` and successfully deployed it:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { onDocumentCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const { setGlobalOptions } = require("firebase-functions/v2");

admin.initializeApp();


// Set the maximum instances to 10 for all functions
setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10 });

const notificationPath = "allUsers/{userId}/notifications/{notificationId}";
exports.sendNotification = onDocumentCreated(notificationPath, async (event) => {
    functions.logger.log("New notificatin document was created"); 
    const data = event.data.after.data();
    const senderUid = data.senderUid;
    const receiverUid = data.receiverUid;
    const notificationOption = data.option;
    functions.logger.log("Retrieved notification fields"); 

    if (notificationOption === "receivedFriendRequest") {
        functions.logger.log("Is option: receivedFriendRequest");
        await onSentFriendRequest(senderUid, receiverUid);
    }
});

async function onSentFriendRequest(ownerId, userId) {
    // Get the owners details
    const owner = await admin.firestore().collection("allUsers").doc(ownerId).get();

    // Get the users details
    const user = await admin.firestore().collection("allUsers").doc(userId).get();

    const userHasNotificationsEnabled = user.data().isPushEnabled;

    functions.logger.log("If this does not print, then your function is not being called");
    if (!userHasNotificationsEnabled) {
        functions.logger.log("User does not have push enabled");
        return;
    }
    functions.logger.log("User has push enabled");

    // Listing all tokens as an array.
    tokens = user.data().messagingTokens;

    // Send message to all tokens
    const response = await admin.messaging().sendEachForMulticast({
        tokens: tokens,
        notification: {
            title: "Neue Freundschaftsanfrage",
            body: `${owner.data().username} möchte mit dir befreundet sein.`,
        },
        data: {
            ownerId: ownerId,
            userId: userId,
            notificationOption: "receivedFriendRequest",
        },
    });

    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            functions.logger.error(
                'Failure sending notification to',
                tokens[index],
                error
            );
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
            }
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);

}
```

Like I said, the deployment was successful. But when a document is added to the `notifications`-collection I get this from my logs:

[image: Logs]

Inside the `Firebase-Console` I see that the function was triggered, I get a `TypeError`.

What am I doing wrong here?
Let me know if you need more information.

**EDIT**

I had an error about `maxScale` which I could fix by adding this line inside my `index.js`-file:

```
    setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10})
```

and this inside my `firebase.json`:

```
  "frameworksBackend": {
    "region": "us-central1",
    "maxInstances": 10
  }
```

Comment: Your error message means `data` is undefined. what is the last log message that was printed? This should help determine which data is undefined.

Comment: @PeterObiechina "New notificatin document was created".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I had smaller issues in my code, like Typos, or the suggested improvements from the answers.

By following this [Sample-Code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/Node-1st-gen/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js) and also looking into `doc` for [`sendEachForMultiCast`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsendeachformulticast) and [`onDocumentCreated`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#node.js) I was able to make it work with this code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { onDocumentCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const { setGlobalOptions } = require("firebase-functions/v2");

admin.initializeApp();


// Set the maximum instances to 10 for all functions
setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10 });

const notificationPath = "allUsers/{userId}/notifications/{notificationId}";
exports.sendNotification = onDocumentCreated(notificationPath, async (event) => {
    functions.logger.log("New notificatin document was created");

    const snapshot = event.data;
    if (!snapshot) {
        console.log("No data associated with the event");
        return;
    }
    const data = snapshot.data();

    // access a particular field as you would any JS property
    const name = data.name;
    const senderUid = data.senderUid;
    const receiverUid = data.receiverUid;
    const notificationOption = data.option;

    if (notificationOption === "recievedFriendRequest") {
        await onSentFriendRequest(senderUid, receiverUid);
    } else {
        functions.logger.log(`is notificationOption: ${notificationOption}`);

    }
});

async function onSentFriendRequest(ownerId, userId) {
    // Get the owners details
    const owner = await admin.firestore().collection("allUsers").doc(ownerId).get();

    // Get the users details
    const user = await admin.firestore().collection("allUsers").doc(userId).get();

    const userHasNotificationsEnabled = user.data().isPushEnabled;

    if (!userHasNotificationsEnabled) {
        functions.logger.log("User does not have push enabled");
        return;
    }
 

    // Listing all tokens as an array.
    tokens = user.data().messagingTokens;

    // Send message to all tokens
    const response = await admin.messaging().sendEachForMulticast({
        tokens: tokens,
        notification: {
            title: "Neue Freundschaftsanfrage",
            body: `${owner.data().username} möchte mit dir befreundet sein.`,
        },
        data: {
            ownerId: ownerId,
            userId: userId,
            notificationOption: "receivedFriendRequest",
        },
    });

    functions.logger.log("Successflully send Notification");


    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.responses.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            functions.logger.error(
                'Failure sending notification to',
                tokens[index],
                error
            );
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/unregistered' || 
                error.code === 'messaging/invalid-argument') {               
                tokensToRemove.push(admin.firestore().collection("allUsers").doc(userId).update({
                    "messagingTokens": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(tokens[index])
                }));
            }
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsend), `admin.messaging().send(message: Message, dryRun?: boolean)` takes in 2 parameters, i.e, message and dryRun. It does not take the token. You should add the token to the message.

```
functions.logger.log("If this does not print, then your function is not being called");
if (!userHasNotificationsEnabled) {
  functions.logger.log("User does not have push enabled");
  return;
}
functions.logger.log("User has push enabled");
const message = {
  notification: {
    title: "Neue Freundschaftsanfrage",
    body: owner.userName + " möchte mit dir befreundet sein.",
  },
  data: {
    ownerId: ownerId,
    userId: userId,
    notificationOption: "recievedFriendRequest",
  },
  token: user.messagingTokens.first, // token should be a single string
};

functions.logger.log(message);
await admin.messaging().send(message);
```

Also, consider using `.onCreate(` instead of `onDocumentCreated(`

Comment: why should I consider using `onCreate` over `onDocumentCreated`?

Comment: Before today, I had not come across `onDocumentCreated` and I assumed `onDocumentCreated` was not from the official docs. That is why I suggested you use the `onCreate` which I currently use and which works for me. But I just googled it and it is from firestore v2 api. So, you can go ahead and use it. It shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: if my solution doesn't work, you can let me know and I will help you debug it.

Comment: I updated my question. I updated my code but it is still not working :/ But at least I get another error now.

Answer (score -1):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
```

When working with Firebase Functions, you should always use the onCreate trigger to listen for document creations instead of the onDocumentCreated function, since it does not exist in the Firebase Functions SDK. Writing with an increased degree of complexity and variation can lead to much more interesting and engaging content, allowing readers to better understand and appreciate the words they are consuming.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document(notificationPath)
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        // Retrieve the document data
        const data = snapshot.data();
        const senderUid = data.senderUid;
        const receiverUid = data.receiverUid;
        const notificationOption = data.notificationOption;

        if (notificationOption === "receivedFriendRequest") {
            await onSentFriendRequest(senderUid, receiverUid);
        }
    });
```

Updating user tokens in your code is essential. To retrieve a user's messagingTokens, the code needs to take a Firestore document snapshot and account for the messagingTokens field. To do that, user.data().messagingTokens must be used. Therefore, the code should be changed as follows: user.data().messagingTokens instead of user.messagingTokens.

```
const userHasNotificationsEnabled = user.data().isPushEnabled;

if (userHasNotificationsEnabled) {
    const tokens = user.data().messagingTokens;

    await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
        tokens: tokens,
        notification: {
            title: "Neue Freundschaftsanfrage",
            body: `${owner.data().userName} möchte mit dir befreundet sein.`,
        },
        data: {
            ownerId: ownerId,
            userId: userId,
            notificationOption: "receivedFriendRequest",
        },
    });
}
```

you can add console.log statement at relevant points.

```
console.log("User has push enabled");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sendMulticast is obsolete/deprecated. Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messagingsendmulticast

Comment: I updated my question and also my code. I am using `sendEachForMulticast` for now, but my code fails somewhere before that. Do you know why ?

Comment: onDocumentCreated is absolutely valid and uses the firebase function v2 naming. You are recommending old v1 triggers, probably because your response was written by ChatGPT. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created